# Transactional support in Camel for Kafka Producer/Consumer

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I aim to construct a transacted camel route that involves:

1. JMS->DB->KafkaProducer
2. KafkaConsumer->DB->JMS

From the related [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-18096) and  Camel documentation, I can see that the transaction support for Kafka consumers and producers is available from Camel 3.17.0

So, I tested a route like below and to my surprise, I found that the transaction part worked as expected.

```
from(JMS:queue1)
//transaction policy doesn't include Kafka Txn manager
.transacted("custom_policy_with_JMS_&_DB_Txn_Managers)
.to(DB:url)
.to(Kafka:topic) // Kafka endpoint is transaction enabled
.end()
```

I couldn't fully understand how this works in the background.
Whether this approach is correct as I don't do anything specifically for Kafka other than adding a couple of properties to make it transactional.

**My questions are:**

1. Even though I did not include Kafka transaction manager in the chained transaction policy ( which only includes JMS and DB Txn Managers ), transaction is taken care of without any issues. Is this the expected usage?
2. What will happen if the rest of the transacted resources (JMS and DB) are XA supported? Will the Kafka commit and rollback still works in tandem with them?
3. I see this support is available for Kafka producers alone, how can I achieve the same transactional guarantee for the Consumer? I don't see any option to enable transactions on consumers. Should I still handle it with manual commit and rollback or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

#1
If you have a proper JTA `PlatformTransactionManager` (Arjuna, etc.), then this will work as desired.

#2
With a JTA `PlatformTransactionManager` you will not be looking at XA transactions.  All transactions will be 1 phase commit, there will be no call to `prepare`.  The transactions are synchronized and share a transactional context.  This `DUPS-OK` mode.  Try setting your JTA logging (TRACE for Arjuna) so that you see the transaction lifecycle logging.

In your case above, you could have the situation where the call to commit to the database is successful, but the commit to kafka fails.  The JMS message would be rolled back.  There would be no rollback for the database.

#3
There is no rollback for kafka consumers.  You could have a transacted route that happens to include a kafka consume after that transaction is started.  The transacted parts would then behave as desired, but you'll never un-consume a kafka message.